# How to return iterable in Python list Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In the following code:

```
states = ["A","B","C","D"]
priors = {"A": 1.0, "B": -1.0, "C": 0, "D": 0}

values = {}    #setup an empty dictionary
for s in states:   
    values[s] = {"Value1": priors[s], "Value2": 3.0} 

max_val = max(values[prevS]["Value1"]*-1 for prevS in states)
```

I need to return max_val **and** the prevS which corresponds to that max value.  How can I do this?

Comment: Why is your `max_val` code in a loop?  it doesn't use the loop variable so it just runs a bunch of times doing the same thing every time redundantly.

Comment: You have 4 max_val's: 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, and 0.0. Which one do you want to preserve?

Comment: I clarified the question to remove that issue.  The heart of it is I am trying to get both the max() and the state prevS that generates it.

Comment: You may want to refresh your memory of [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> max((values[prevS]["Value1"]*-1, prevS) for prevS in states)
(1.0, 'B')
```

This makes a tuple of the value and its prevS value and takes the max of those.  Since the "value" comes first the max will operate on that first, and the prevS value will only be used to break ties.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is that you want?

```
states = ["A","B","C","D"]
priors = {"A": 1.0, "B": -1.0, "C": 0, "D": 0}

values = ((item[0], item[1]*-1) for item in priors.items() if item[0] in states)

print max(values, key=lambda i:i[1])
```

Result

```
('B', 1.0)
```

Or this:

```
states = ["A","B","C","D"]
priors = {"A": 1.0, "B": -1.0, "C": 0, "D": 0}

values = {item[0]:{'Value1':item[1]*-1, 'Value2':3.0} for item in priors.items() if item[0] in states}

print  max(values.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['Value1'])
```

Result

```
('B', {'Value2': 3.0, 'Value1': 1.0})
```